# Querying the records from LeadHistory

Tags: soql, id, custom-profile

After querying the records from the LeadHistory, timing difference is occurring when compared to system time and records time.

Unable to understand why the difference is coming like that?

Comment: Could be an issue of time zone.Check your user's time zone

Comment: What timie field do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

In backend all time stamps(dateTime field values) are stored as Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm

If you are running History report Date time field values will be displayed in User time zone.